# How do I set the default database in Sql Server from code?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2000

I can't seem to figure out how to set the default database in Sql Server from code. This can be either .Net code or T-Sql (T-Sql would be nice since it would be easy to use in any language). I searched Google and could only find how to do it in Sql Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

from: http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/sp_da-di_6.htm

```
sp_defaultdb [@loginame =] 'login' , [@defdb =] 'database'
```

Comment: Note that this is mainly appropriate for older SQL versions; the answer below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/106015/112764) is better for 2005 & up.

Answer (score 30):

`ALTER LOGIN` should be used for SQL Server 2005 or later:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx

```
ALTER LOGIN <login_name> WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = <default_database>
```

`sp_defaultdb` eventually will be removed from SQL Server:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181738.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Sql Server 2000 and the ALTER LOGIN command doesn't appear to work in it: Incorrect syntax near 'LOGIN'.

Comment: I tried single 'quotes' and round (brackets) and was getting syntax error too. Then i changed to square brackets and it worked!
ALTER LOGIN [login_name] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [default_database]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for SQL Server in general (2005-up); but the OP stated SQL 2000 (but didn't tag it correctly), so in that case it's not, and the accepted answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Stephen.

As a note, if you are using Windows Authentication, the `@loginname` is `YourDomain\YourLogin` (probably obvious to everybody else, but took me a couple tries.

```
sp_defaultdb @loginame='YourDomain\YourLogin', @defdb='YourDatabase'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to change which database you are using after you are logged in, you can use the USE command.  E.g. USE Northwind.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-select-database.htm