# SQL Server - new user has access to master database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I created a new SQL server with a database in Azure and after logging in with the admin account I added a new user that I wanted to only have access to one database.

In SSMS I right clicked on `mynewdatabase` database and selected New Query.

I executed

```
CREATE USER mynewuser WITH PASSWORD ='good password here';
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER mynewuser ;
```

Now after logging in as mynewuser I can still see the master database.

The question is how do I restrict `mynewuser` to only access `mynewdatabase`?

I'm sure this is something basic.

Comment: You can change the default database using ALTER USER, example here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105950/how-do-i-set-the-default-database-in-sql-server-from-code. The user will still the database listed but won't be able to access it. The default setting just changes the default database that the user will connect to unless they explicitly specify which one to connect to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, including Azure SQL DB, all users can can see all system databases in sys.databases. This is not the same as being able to connect to them or run queries in them. This does not disclose any sensitive information as these are system databases and whether you saw them listed or not you would know they were there. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx#Anchor_0.

Based on the steps you describe, you have created a contained user that should not be able to connect to the master database or run queries in Azure SQL DB.