# How do I set the default database in SQL Server using T-SQL? (updated)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Corrective update/replacement for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105950/), as applicable to currently supported versions of SQL.

How do I **set** the default database for a particular login, using T-SQL code?

The accepted answer uses a deprecated system stored procedure; the MSDN/BOL documentation prefers the more standard & current "ALTER LOGIN" syntax, as shown in the newer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/106015/112764) from [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10363/tim).

Comment: PS: Mods, if this is not the appropriate way to correct the old Q/A/mistake, plz let me know.  I read two meta-posts about it and it sounded like the recommended method.

Comment: The issue is your question. No one wise will click on a link they do not trust. What is your question, really? Do you need advice how to script this out from SSMS? Why can you not use MSDN's [ALTER LOGIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx) page for reference before coming here? Show your work...

Comment: @clifton_h I'm confused. The links are all SO. I'm merely trying to correct a problem with a similar question that has an obsolete accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/106015/112764

> ALTER LOGIN should be used for SQL Server 2005 or later:
>   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx
>
> `ALTER LOGIN <login_name> WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = <default_database>`

Sample usage:
`ALTER LOGIN [JoeShmoe] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [tempdb]`

Extra note: although MSDN/BOL pages have been updated to *exclude* 2005 from the "applies to" list (it usually reads "SQL Server (starting with 2008)" or similarly), in this case, I verified that the command still works on 2005.